# colormap for imshow in GUIDE axes object

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I have using GUIDE to display raster data inside of a axes object. But I want to colormap to be the 'colorcube' map. Right now I set this with two lines:

```
function mapImage(data, box)
low = min(min(data));
high = max(max(data));
imshow(data, [low high], 'Parent', box);
colormap(box, colorcube);
```

Update:

I do think the colormap is working, but what it when it hits the colorcube command it pops up a figure. I don't want that.

I did get it to stop doing that by the following, but when I do this, I get a flash in all 4 axes objects for a second when they all switch to the colcube map (and then they go back).

Odd.

```
function mapImage(data, box)
low = min(min(data));
high = max(max(data));
cube = colorcube(64);
imshow(data, [low high], 'Parent', box, 'ColorMap', cube);
```

Comment: Seems to work here (initiallizing `box = gca`, `data = randn(10,10)`. I use R2015a

Comment: @LuisMendo see update. This is getting weird.

Comment: Perhaps add some screenshots to exemplify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your "figure" actually a dialog?

Running this code -> you get a dialog and a second figure which is created when the colormap line is run:

```
close all
d = dialog;
ax = axes ( 'parent', d );
colormap ( ax, colorcube );
```

Where as if it is a figure then it works as expected:

```
close all
d = figure
ax = axes ( 'parent', d );
colormap ( ax, colorcube );
```

You could also fix this feature by specify the size of the colorcube map using a dialog:

```
close all
d = dialog;
ax = axes ( 'parent', d );
colormap ( ax, colorcube(64) );
```

Comment: all my figures are in a GUIDE GUI, But the last suggestion colormap(ax, colorcube(64)) did the trick. Thank you.